# How to get duplicate rows with multiple conditions in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks something like these

```
  Name      Amount     Symbol            Date      TC  
1  ABC         100         IN        1/1/2021   FALSE
2  ABC          50         DV        1/1/2021   FALSE
3  DEF         200         IN        1/1/2021   FALSE
4  HIJ          50        BUY        2/1/2021    TRUE
5  DEF         200        BUY        1/1/2021    TRUE
6  DEF         200        TAC        1/1/2021   FALSE
```

What I want to do is there first I will delete all rows with the symbol with TAC. So there won't be the last row as its symbol is TAC.

Afterwards, I need to get a DF with all duplicate rows of `Name, Amount and Date`. So the output I desire is

```
  Name   Amount    Symbol        Date      TC
3  DEF      200        IN    1/1/2021   FALSE
5  DEF      200       BUY    1/1/2021    TRUE
```

the other rows wont appear due to the following reasons:

```
1 - ABC is there in row 2 but the amounts are different
2 - reason as 1
4 - the HIJ is not repeated
6 - This row is repeated in 3 and 5 but it got filtered out as its symbol is TAC.
```

I hope it's clear. I tried different solutions but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and set `keep=False` in order to mark all duplicates as `True`.

```py
# Drop 'TAC' rows
df = df[df['Symbol'] != 'TAC']

# Drop duplicates on Name, Amount and Date
df = df.duplicated(subset=['Name','Amount','Date'], keep=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case filter and find the duplicate

```
out = df.loc[df.Symbol.ne('TAC') & df[['Name','Amount','Date']].duplicated(keep=False)].copy()
Out[30]: 
  Name  Amount Symbol      Date     TC
3  DEF     200     IN  1/1/2021  False
5  DEF     200    BUY  1/1/2021   True
```

Comment: what is meant by ```.ne``` ??

Comment: @Derik002 `.ne` means "not equal to" and is equivalent to `!=` or `<>` in other languages.